# How to make a "custom" auto incrementing ID

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, laravel-filament

I have an app with invoices, I set the invoice id to auto-increment.

my client wants the ID to include the year and restart at 1 when a year passes. for instance ids could look like this.

2023-344
2023-345
2023-346
etc...
until we reach 2024 in which case the next id would be
2024-1

I've never attempted to customize the id column in mysql and I am not sure how a change like this could affect the indexing speed. I am wondering what the best way to handle this would be.

my app is in laravel and my database is in mysql

Comment: Do it in the app.  SQL is not set up to make such easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add seperated column `invoice_id`. And can write new method in your model:

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->string('invoice_id');
   $table->index('invoice_id');
});
```

```
public static function createNewInvoice() {
    $currentYear = now()->year;
    $lastInvoice = Invoice::where('year', $currentYear)->orderBy('number', 'desc')->first();
    $number = $lastInvoice ? $lastInvoice->number + 1 : 1;

    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->year = $currentYear;
    $invoice->number = $number;
    $invoice->save();

    return $invoice;
}
```

You can modify method as you want.

Comment: Where would I call the createNewInvoice method?

Comment: You can call it when you create new invoice in Controller, like $invoice = new Invoice(); $invoice->createNewInvoice(); You can modify logic as you want. it's just an example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you CAN ONLY use auto_increment on INT or BIGINT fields, you can't use "-" or any other characters.

I don't know how the model layer in Laravel works, but you can alter the MySQL table and add a Generated Column. [Explantion here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html).

Maybe you can have something like this:

CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT);
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN c2 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) + "-" + ID_sequence;